# Утечка памяти python, dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, утечка-памяти

Пишу парсер, который 24/7 работает на сервере. Спустя несколько часов работы он сжирает всю память.

```
def request():
    pool = ThreadPool()
    headers = {'Host': 'api.******.ru',
               'auth-token': constants.auth_token[0],
               'locale': 'en', 'os': 'android', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
               'content-length': '323', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip', 'user-agent': 'okhttp/3.6.0'}
    urls = []
    for i in range(len(items)):
        url = 'https://api.*******.ru/*********/' + str(
            (items[i].split('?')[0])[26:len(items[i])]) + '?currency=RUB'
        urls.append(url)
    rs = (grequests.get(u, data=headers, headers=headers, timeout=2) for u in urls)
    res = grequests.map(rs)
    result = []
    sum = []
    for j in range(len(items)):
        try:
            sum.append(res[j])
            sum.append(j)
            result.append(sum)
            sum = []
        except:
            pass
    try:
        pool.map(parser, result)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    gc.collect()

    muppy.print_summary()
except:
    return
return


def main():
    while True:
        request()
```

В итоге имеем то, что постоянно растут некоторые объекты

```
    types |   # objects |   total size
==================================== | =========== | ============
                         <class 'str |       34266 |      4.66 MB
                        <class 'dict |        5488 |      1.51 MB
                        <class 'code |       11007 |    905.22 KB
                        <class 'type |        1436 |    762.77 KB
                        <class 'list |        1852 |    150.30 KB
                       <class 'tuple |        4002 |    148.17 KB
                         <class 'set |         283 |    147.06 KB
          <class 'wrapper_descriptor |        2352 |    101.06 KB
                     <class 'weakref |        2331 |    100.16 KB
  <class 'builtin_function_or_method |        1662 |     64.92 KB
           <class 'getset_descriptor |        1611 |     62.93 KB
                  <class 're.Pattern |         154 |     62.61 KB
                 function (__init__) |         849 |     59.70 KB
           <class 'method_descriptor |        1491 |     58.24 KB
                 <class 'abc.ABCMeta |         109 |     54.77 KB



                            types |   # objects |   total size
==================================== | =========== | ============
                         <class 'str |       38925 |      4.97 MB
                        <class 'dict |        5798 |      1.56 MB
                        <class 'code |       11007 |    905.22 KB
                        <class 'type |        1436 |    762.82 KB
                        <class 'list |        1928 |    177.50 KB
                       <class 'tuple |        4101 |    151.56 KB
                         <class 'set |         310 |    151.12 KB
                     <class 'weakref |        2357 |    101.28 KB
          <class 'wrapper_descriptor |        2352 |    101.06 KB
  <class 'builtin_function_or_method |        1680 |     65.62 KB
           <class 'getset_descriptor |        1611 |     62.93 KB
                  <class 're.Pattern |         154 |     62.61 KB
                 function (__init__) |         849 |     59.70 KB
           <class 'method_descriptor |        1491 |     58.24 KB
                 <class 'abc.ABCMeta |         109 |     54.48 KB
```

В чем может быть причина утечки?

Comment: А в чем смысл `sum = []`? Можно ведь было без него: `result.append((res[j], j))`. Да и перед сборкой почему бы не обнулить неиспользуемые ссылки, например `result = None`

Comment: А какая у вас задержка между запросами? Так ли необходимо использовать потоки?

Comment: @gil9red задержка между запросами ~2 секунды. тут много костылей, который пол года назад еще сделал, сейчас поправлю

Comment: @gil9red все неиспользуемые ссылки обнулил, все равно память утекает..

Comment: например в том, что gc.collect() надо использовать в блоке finally: после последнего из except:

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была все же в библиотеке grequests. Решил ее переходом на aiohttp.

Comment: Почему вы так уверены, что проблема была именно в библиотеке `grequest`?